# Prove that even though $p(x,y)>0$ for all points, where $p(x,y)=x^2+(xy-1)^2$ there does not exist an $a>0$ such that $p(x,y) \geq a$ for all points

Tags: real-analysis

I’ve attempted this question by assuming there is such an $a$ and then trying to find a point $(x,y)$ such that $p(x,y)<a$ but I’m struggling. Is this the right way to go or is there another way of proving this?

Answer (score 4):

Just a hint: Consider the sequence $(x_n,y_n)=(\frac{1}{n},n)$ and calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}p(x_n,y_n)$.